# Computing $\int_0^1 \frac{x^{y-1}}{s-x} dx$

Tags: calculus, probability, sequences-and-series

Is a nice expression for $h(s)$ known for $y\in (0,1)$?

$$h(s)=c \int_0^1 \frac{x^{y-1}}{s-x}  dx$$

This is the Stieltjes Transformation of $\operatorname{Beta}(y, 1)$ random variable where $c$ is normalizing constant

Comment: This is incomplete beta function.

Comment: It can also be represented via Lerch Transcendent. For $y\in\Bbb Q$, there is a closed form via [this incomplete beta finite series expansion](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2006.06515.pdf)